# How to correct processing exceptions in linqXml?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I work with Linq xml in C#, but I don't know how to correct processing exception, when some elements is null.
For example, I need get some value of attribute, but this attribute can be null, or can be null some part of path. I do like this:

```
public static string GetImage(this HtmlNode element)
    {
        var result = "";
        try
        {
            return result = element.Element("div").Element("a").Element("img")?.GetAttribute("src").Value;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Maybe I can do it easy?
Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already are using C# 6.0, then use [null conditional operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx) as you already did after `Element("img")`:

```
return element?.Element("div")?.Element("a")?.Element("img")?.GetAttribute("src")?.Value;
```